# How to use Window Function in MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, window-functions, azure-synapse

I'm creating a SQL Script in Azure Synapse to transform dimension data from a Staging table [Source] to its Storage table [Target].

The target is created with a key using ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id WHERE s.name = 'prd' and t.name = 'dim_stations')
    CREATE TABLE prd.dim_stations
    WITH
    (
        DISTRIBUTION = HASH(station_key),
        CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
    )
    AS  SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [station_id],[station_name],[station_latitude],[sattion_longitude] ASC) AS station_key, 
            [station_id],
            [station_name]          AS name,
            [station_latitude]      AS latitude,
            [sattion_longitude]     AS longitude
        FROM
            stg.stations;
GO
```

I'm trying to handle SCD Type 1 in the table using `MERGE` but I can't handle the key in the `Insert` Statement with an error that means **Window Functions Could Only be Used with `SELECT` Statement**.

The `Merge` Statement:

```
MERGE INTO prd.dim_stations AS p 
USING stg.stations AS s
ON s.station_id = p.station_id
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
    p.latitude = s.station_latitude,
    p.longitude = s.sattion_longitude,
    p.name = s.station_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (station_key, station_id, name, latitude, longitude)
    VALUES
    (
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [station_id],[station_name],[station_latitude],[sattion_longitude] ASC),
        s.station_id,
        s.station_name,
        s.station_latitude,
        s.sattion_longitude
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OPTION(LABEL= 'MERGE Stations')
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a new `station_key` won't collide with an existing `station_key`. i.e. you could have existing `station_key=50` in your dimension, and your existing select can obviously generate 50 for a dimension record that has nothing to do with it. I also suggest that you don't use merge, use seperate insert and update statements. Merge has a lot of bugs and doesn't support a lot of features.

Comment: Oh, You're right.
So how can I handle the delete step I I won't use merge? the condition to make it is similar to the one that will be used for Insert

Comment: Nevermind my question, I can differentiate with different join types xD.
Thank you for your help and your quick response

Comment: To get around your specific error, instead of `USING stg.stations` you can use CTE syntax to pre-define the table being used

Comment: You don't delete from SCD1, nor is there any sign of delete in your existing query. Also I'll mention again: your surrogate key logic is incorrect

Comment: Okay, what is your recommendation for the key column logic? I can't use the row_number or identity

Comment: Why can't you use an identity? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity

Comment: My staging table is an external table that does not support identity and the storage table is created using CTAS from staging table

Comment: There are a whole bunch of things very wrong with this. But how about I just answer your immediate question. The most obvious way to get around this would be to create a view with `ROW_NUMBER()` in it and use that view for both the CTAS and the MERGE. You need to use that view in the `USING` part of the merge, not the `VALUES` part. You don't even need to use a view but it's the smart way to not have duplicate code (even if the duplicate code doesn't do what you need)

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'm doing this as an exercise for practicing how to build DW and I will appreciate if you help me know the whole bunch of the things that are very wrong. I have CSV In ADLS that is staged using external tables in Dedicated SQL Pool and then a script to create the Storage table from it

Comment: In short I suggest you do some reading on what a surrogate key is used for, it's purpose etc. Basically when a new dimension record arrives, it needs to generate a new unique surrogate key, and this code isn't guaranteed to do that. Also if you are building analytics from only one source system, and only for SCD11, there actually isn't any technical reason to need a surrogate key, it's just good practice in case you add more source systems later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this approach with out using the SELECT statement in the Merge.

For example I have created 2 table Called the Source01 and Target01 to implement **SCD Type 01** which will perform the update and Insert.
**Source:**

```
CREATE  TABLE Source01 (
id INT,

name VARCHAR(50),

age INT,

city VARCHAR(50)

);
```

**Target Create statement:**

```
CREATE  TABLE Target01 (
id INT,
name VARCHAR(50),
age INT,
city VARCHAR(50),
row_num INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_Target01 PRIMARY  KEY  NONCLUSTERED (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
DISTRIBUTION = HASH(id),
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
);  
INSERT  INTO Target01 (id, name, age, city, row_num)SELECT
id,

name,

age,

city,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER  BY id) AS row_num

FROM Source01;
```

I am using the ROW_NUMBER() function just over  ID column. in the target table.Before perform the Merge statement  row count 14.
[image]

Now at the source01 I am updating 2 records. and Inserting 1 row.

```
-- Update age and city for John Doe
UPDATE Source01
SET age = 26,
city = 'Chicago'
WHERE id = 1;
-- Update age and city for Jane Smith
UPDATE Source01
SET age = 33,
city = 'San Francisco'
WHERE id = 2;
-- Insert a new record in the Source table
INSERT  INTO Source01 VALUES(16, 'Samantha Green', 31, 'Austin');
```

[image]
[image]

Before the Source table is updated
[image]
[image]
Using the **MERGE** statement. **Update** 2 records in the Target table and Inserting new row.

**MERGE Statement:**

```
MERGE  INTO Target01 AS T
USING Source01 AS S
ON T.id = S.id
WHEN  MATCHED  THEN
UPDATE  SET
T.name = S.name,
T.age = S.age,
T.city = S.city
WHEN  NOT  MATCHED  THEN
INSERT (id, name, age, city)
VALUES (S.id, S.name, S.age, S.city);
```

[image]
After Update
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, The problem here is that the row_num will be always inserted as null

Comment: @Baseem Mustafa So you want the row num  to be as the NOT NULL Value?

Comment: yes, I need to maintain an id for the storage table after moving staging data into it

Comment: @Baseem Mustafa
 let me try for the approach and will update you.

Comment: @BassemMustafa This Time I have tried using the SELECT statement
In the MERGE Query. so please try this and let me know if it help

MERGE INTO Target01 AS T
USING (
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        age,
        city,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num
    FROM Source01
) AS S
ON T.id = S.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        T.name = S.name,
        T.age = S.age,
        T.city = S.city
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, age, city, row_num)
    VALUES (S.id, S.name, S.age, S.city, S.row_num);

Comment: I tried the MERGE and I dont see any NULL values in the Row Num() column.
try this and do let me know if it helps

Comment: Though I learned that it is not the best solution to use ROW_NUMBER as a surrogate key, Your solution worked fine. Thank you